# What is the liquid leaking from my Ford Aspire Petrol Manual 2017 (India)?

Tags: ford, leak, aspire

The fluid one seems to leak when I park my car in my parking lot. It does not leak when the car is standing still. It starts to leak during parking.

The fluid does not leak when I back out of my parking lot. It only seems to leak when I enter the parking lot. I have checked by getting out of the car immediately after taking my car out of parking but nothing leaks.

I have also checked when the car is parked in other places. Nothing leaks. Nor is there a trail when I drive the car in first gear at slow speeds.

The fluid which comes out seems like water, though I have not checked with tissue paper.

I recently took my car for servicing. They reported leaking brake oil, so I assumed that the leak must be the brake oil. They sealed the hole in the brake oil canister. I checked the car at the service center, there was no leak. However, when I parked the car at my cursed parking lot again, it was leaking for some time again.

Is it water from my A/C? It seems the car leaks a lot more when the A/C has been on, even though I can not completely confirm the correlation as the A/C fan sometimes turns on automatically without my switching it on.

This problem is occurring from a few months, almost around the start of winter. I also see water marks in other parking lots around my car, is it possibly something being caused by the humid, cold and foggy conditions?

I had an idea occur to me that it is possibly my transmission oil leaking when I put the car in reverse gear. However, I have checked that as well, and that does not cause the leak. Then I moved on to checking if holding the clutch for a long time was doing it, the answer again, was no.

I am inexperienced with cars, and I am worried that it will break down in the middle of the road one day.

I have checked all fluids that can easily be checked including engine oil, washer fluid, coolant and brake oil. They all seem normal right now. I cannot check the clutch fluid and the transmission oil easily.

I got worried as my gear shift stick got stuck for a minute yesterday. I thought I had run out of transmission oil due to leak. After I exit and entered the car again, the stick started to work smoothly. It is still working smoothly today with no problems shifting gears. Perfectly smooth.

Please help me diagnose this.

Comment: The best way to diagnose what it is you're looking at is by the look and feel of the liquid, as well as the position of the leak itself in comparison to where it's at on the vehicle (location of wet spot as compared to where the vehicle was sitting). Oil will be very slick and thick. Water from AC will be colorless, odorless, and very thin. The drain from the AC is located near the firewall of the engine bay and usually on the passenger side. You'd smell antifreeze (usually sickly sweet smell). Transmission fluid will be viscous, but thinner than engine oil. It may be red in color.